# Adding an audio element in the nodes of familytree.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add audio to the nodes of familytree, the button is displayed but i cannot get it executed,nothing logs, which means the functions is not called. the audio and the link work individually

```
import React, { Component,useRef, useState } from "react";
import FamilyTree, { Button } from "@balkangraph/familytree.js";
import "./Targaryen.css";
import ReactAudioPlayer from 'react-audio-player';

const playSound = (soundUrl) => {
  if (soundUrl) {
    const audioPlayer = new Audio(soundUrl);
    audioPlayer.play();
    return soundUrl;
  }
};

export default class Chart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.divRef = React.createRef();



  }

  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.family = new FamilyTree(this.divRef.current, {
      nodes: this.props.nodes,

      scaleInitial: FamilyTree.match.height,
      miniMap: true,
      subtreeSeparation: 20,
      mode: "dark",
      nodeBinding: {
        field_0: "name",
        field_1: "Aliases",
        field_2: "throne",
        img_0: "img",
        img_1: "sigil",
        dragon: "dragon",
        Sound: ({ Sound }) => {
          const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
          console.log("Sound");

          const togglePlay = () => {
            console.log("Button clicked");
            setIsPlaying((prevIsPlaying) => !prevIsPlaying);
          };

          console.log("Node data:", Sound);

          return (
            <div className="audio-player">
              <ReactAudioPlayer
                src={Sound}
                onPlay={() => setIsPlaying(true)}
                onPause={() => setIsPlaying(false)}
                onEnded={() => setIsPlaying(false)}
              />
              <button
                className={`play-button ${isPlaying ? "playing" : ""}`}
                onClick={() => {
                  togglePlay();
                  playSound(Sound);
                }}
              >
                {isPlaying ? "Pause" : "Play"}
              </button>
            </div>
          );
        },
      },    
      clinks: [
        { from: 4, to: 14, template: "myTemplate" },
        { from: 13, to: 14, template: "myTemplate" },
        { from: 18, to: 19, template: "myTemplate" },
        { from: 27, to: 35, template: "myTemplate" },
        { from: 60, to: 40, template: "myTemplate" },
        { from: 43, to: 52, template: "myTemplate" },
        { from: 52, to: 53, template: "myTemplate" },
        { from: 50, to: 54, template: "myTemplate" },
        { from: 66, to: 71, template: "myTemplate" },
      ],
      editForm: {
        titleBinding: "name",
        photoBinding: "img",
        generateElementsFromFields: true,
        addMore: "Add more elements",
        addMoreBtn: "Add elements",
        addMoreFieldName: "Element name",
        elements: [
          { type: "textbox", label: "", binding: "throne" },
          [      { type: "textbox", label: "Name", binding: "name" },      { type: "textbox", label: "Dragon", binding: "dragon" },    ],
          [{ type: "textbox", label: "Alias", binding: "Aliases" }],
          [      { type: "textbox", label: "Birth Date", binding: "Born" },      { type: "textbox", label: "Death Date", binding: "Died" },    ],
          [{ type: "textbox", label: "Culture", binding: "culture" }],
        ],
        buttons: {
          edit: null,
          share: null,
          pdf: {
            icon: FamilyTree.icon.pdf(24, 24, "#fff"),
            text: "Save as PDF",
          },
          ft: {
            icon: FamilyTree.icon.ft(24, 24, "#fff"),
            text: "Play Sound",
            onClick: (node) => {
              console.log("Playing sound:");
              const soundUrl =               playSound(node.data.Sound);

              if (soundUrl != null && soundUrl !== '') {
                console.log("Playing sound:", soundUrl);
                const audioPlayer = new Audio(soundUrl);
                audioPlayer.play();
              }else{
                console.log("no sound")

              }
            }
          }
        },
      },
    });
  }

  render() {

    return <div id="tree" ref={this.divRef}></div>;
  }
}
```

I the data file i pass the link as text like this from the data file

```
Sound:"https://file-examples.com/storage/fe0b804ac5640668798b8d0/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
```

i cant figure out what i am doing wrong,
i also tried like this and display the button in the textbox type in the elements but only the link is displayed as text, i tried to use something else exempt textbox as a type of the element but the nodes do not open when i do that.

```
import React, { Component,useRef, useState } from "react";
import FamilyTree, { Button } from "@balkangraph/familytree.js";
import "./Targaryen.css";
import ReactAudioPlayer from 'react-audio-player';

const playSound = (soundUrl) => {
  if (soundUrl) {
    const audioPlayer = new Audio(soundUrl);
    audioPlayer.play();
    return soundUrl;
  }
};
export default class Chart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.divRef = React.createRef();



  }

  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.family = new FamilyTree(this.divRef.current, {
      nodes: this.props.nodes,

      scaleInitial: FamilyTree.match.height,
      miniMap: true,
      subtreeSeparation: 20,
      mode: "dark",
      nodeBinding: {
        field_0: "name",
        field_1: "Aliases",
        field_2: "throne",
        img_0: "img",
        img_1: "sigil",
        dragon: "dragon",
        Sound: ({ Sound }) => {
          const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
          console.log("Sound");

          const togglePlay = () => {
            console.log("Button clicked");
            setIsPlaying((prevIsPlaying) => !prevIsPlaying);
          };

          console.log("Node data:", Sound);

          return (
            <div className="audio-player">
              <ReactAudioPlayer
                src={Sound}
                onPlay={() => setIsPlaying(true)}
                onPause={() => setIsPlaying(false)}
                onEnded={() => setIsPlaying(false)}
              />
              <button
                className={`play-button ${isPlaying ? "playing" : ""}`}
                onClick={() => {
                  togglePlay();
                  playSound(Sound);
                }}
              >
                {isPlaying ? "Pause" : "Play"}
              </button>
            </div>
          );
        },
      },    
      clinks: [
        { from: 4, to: 14, template: "myTemplate" },
        { from: 13, to: 14, template: "myTemplate" },
        { from: 18, to: 19, template: "myTemplate" },
        { from: 27, to: 35, template: "myTemplate" },
        { from: 60, to: 40, template: "myTemplate" },
        { from: 43, to: 52, template: "myTemplate" },
        { from: 52, to: 53, template: "myTemplate" },
        { from: 50, to: 54, template: "myTemplate" },
        { from: 66, to: 71, template: "myTemplate" },
      ],
      editForm: {
        titleBinding: "name",
        photoBinding: "img",
        generateElementsFromFields: true,
        addMore: "Add more elements",
        addMoreBtn: "Add elements",
        addMoreFieldName: "Element name",
        elements: [
          { type: "textbox", label: "", binding: "throne" },
          [      { type: "textbox", label: "Name", binding: "name" },      { type: "textbox", label: "Dragon", binding: "dragon" },    ],
          [{ type: "textbox", label: "Alias", binding: "Aliases" }],
          [      { type: "textbox", label: "Birth Date", binding: "Born" },      { type: "textbox", label: "Death Date", binding: "Died" },    ],
          [{ type: "textbox", label: "Culture", binding: "culture" }],
          [{ type: "textbox", label: "Sound", binding: "Sound" }],

        ],
        buttons: {
          edit: null,
          share: null,
          pdf: {
            icon: FamilyTree.icon.pdf(24, 24, "#fff"),
            text: "Save as PDF",
          },
        },
      },
    });
  }

  render() {

    return <div id="tree" ref={this.divRef}></div>;
  }
}
```